How to return nodes and relationships only if a certain condition is true in cypher
In my database, I want certain nodes and relationships returned if items in 2 aggregated lists do not match. To be specific, a user has certain accesses and role. I want to pinpoint those users whose current accesses do not match with the accesses required by their roles.
This is my main query to achieve this:
match(u:User)-[r1:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(ri:RoleInfo)-[r2:CURRENT]->(rr:Role{roleName:'Claims Specialist'})-[rel:REQUIRES_ACCESS_TO]->(e:Entitlement)
match (u)-[r3:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(ua:UserAccount)-[r4:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(ei:EntitlementInfo)-[r5:CURRENT]->(en:Entitlement)
with apoc.coll.sort(collect(distinct e.entitlementName)) as reqdAccesses, e,u,r1, ri, r2, rr,r3,ua,r4,ei,r5,en, rel, apoc.coll.sort(collect(distinct  en.entitlementName)) as currentAccesses
WHERE any(item in currentAccesses where not item in reqdAccesses) and size(reqdAccesses) <> size(currentAccesses)
return e,u,r1,ri,r2,r3,ua,r4,ei,r5,en,rel,rr

Now as per the data both the lists for this role have a mismatch as shown by below query and output.
match(u:User)-[r1:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(ri:RoleInfo)-[r2:CURRENT]->(rr:Role{roleName:'Claims Specialist'})-[rel:REQUIRES_ACCESS_TO]->(e:Entitlement)
match (u)-[r3:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(ua:UserAccount)-[r4:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(ei:EntitlementInfo)-[r5:CURRENT]->(en:Entitlement)
return apoc.coll.sort(collect(distinct en.entitlementName)) as currentAccesses, apoc.coll.sort(collect(DISTINCT e.entitlementName)) as reqdAccesses

output:
currentAccesses 
["Claims Adjustment Portal", "Claims Management System", "Customer Relationship Management System", "Electronic Health Records System", "Fraud Detection Platform", "Patient Portal"]
reqdAccesses
["Claims Adjustment Portal", "Claims Management System", "Customer Feedback System", "Fraud Detection Platform", "MEDSTAR CRM"]

I still do not get the data returned. Is there anything wrong in my main query ?

I have tried removing the 'and' in last where clause where actual comparison happens. So if i remove the size from it, I get results for this. But for all other roles as well where there are no differences in both the lists.
If I remove the 'any' part of the where clause and just compare the difference in size of both lists, I don't get result for anything, irrespective of the difference.


Your first query checks 'Claims Analyst' while the second one checks 'Claims Specialist'. Does the second query return results for 'Claims Analyst'? (I know this is a bit obvious, but just checking.)

Typo, my bad. Thanks for pointing out. So Yes, I want to pinpoint the violations in role Claims Specialist. Added one more point in original post.

It looks right to me, so I'm not being much help. Does it make any difference if you take the sorting out? I'm wondering if there's a side effect in the apoc calls? (Clutching at straws now.)
The WHERE clause is giving me the expected results for the two lists if I use WITHs to alias the lists to 'currentAccesses' and 'reqdAccesses' then return the result of the WHERE

Aggregating functions like COLLECT aggregate on grouping keys.
Your first query uses a very large set of grouping keys (e,u,r1,ri,r2,rr,r3,ua,r4,ei,r5,en,rel):
with apoc.coll.sort(collect(distinct e.entitlementName)) as reqdAccesses, e,u,r1, ri, r2, rr,r3,ua,r4,ei,r5,en, rel, apoc.coll.sort(collect(distinct  en.entitlementName)) as currentAccesses

Because that clause includes e and en as grouping keys, the collect(distinct e.entitlementName) and collect(distinct  en.entitlementName) aggregated lists will each only contain a single item.
Your second query specifies no grouping keys, and therefore works as you intended:
return apoc.coll.sort(collect(distinct en.entitlementName)) as currentAccesses, apoc.coll.sort(collect(DISTINCT e.entitlementName)) as reqdAccesses

This query should identify every user that has accesses that they are not entitled to, and return them and a list of their violations:
MATCH (u:User)-[r1:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(ri:RoleInfo)-[r2:CURRENT]->(rr:Role{roleName:'Claims Specialist'})-[rel:REQUIRES_ACCESS_TO]->(e:Entitlement)
MATCH (u)-[r3:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(ua:UserAccount)-[r4:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(ei:EntitlementInfo)-[r5:CURRENT]->(en:Entitlement)
WITH u, COLLECT(DISTINCT e.entitlementName) AS entitledAccesses, COLLECT(DISTINCT en.entitlementName) AS currentAccesses
WITH u, [c IN currentAccesses WHERE NOT c IN entitledAccesses] AS violations
WHERE SIZE(violations) > 0
RETURN u, violations


I was thinking, "Where's cybersam when you need him?". Aggregation - so obvious, now!

That's the thing. I added some line so that I get violations even when current Accesses is missing an item from entitledAccesses. Thanks a ton cybersam.
